# Is there a set of 6 lines that satisfies the following condition?

Tags: induction, contest-math

Basically the question is:

Is there are set $A$ of $6$ lines such that

1. For each subset $B$ of $5$ lines, there are always two points such that every line in $B$ passes through at least one of them.
2. There are no two points such that every line in $A$ passes through at least one.

I have tried many configurations, but have not found one. I think that it is possible

It comes from building up the base case of a more general problem that says that for every finite set $A$ of lines, if every subset $B$ of $k^2+1$ lines passes through $k$ points, then every line in $A$ passes through $k$ points.

The question above is asking the opposite for $k=2.$ The base case is $k=3,$ but I am not able to see why we cannot just use the base case $k=2.$ $k=1$ does not work because there are many configurations that disprove it (3 lines are necessary, not 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should satisfy all of the required criteria.

[image]

Also look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_plane

And, you should be able so swap "lines" and "points" and the proposition will still be true.

Comment: This definitely works. Thank you very much. Just wondering, what exactly is the reason this works? Does it have something to do with $K_4$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.  A diagram is below.  It is basically a quadrilateral $ABCD$ with the two diagonals drawn to make six lines where no two lines are parallel.  If you number the lines
$$1\quad AB\\2\quad AC\\3 \quad AD\\4\quad BC\\5 \quad CD\\ 6 \quad BD$$ we have that
$A$ is on lines $1,2,3$, $B$ is on lines $1,4,6$, $C$ is on lines $2,4,5$, and $D$ is on lines $3,5,6$.  Any subset of five lines contains one of the triplets and you pick that point plus the intersection of the other two lines.

[image]

Comment: Forgive me if I missed something, but how does a subset containing lines $1,2,3,4$ and $6$ satisfy the requirements? Just an example. $2,4$ and $6$ force the two points to be $B$ and $C$ and $3$ does not go through either.

Comment: $1,2,3$ meet in point $A$ and $4,6$ meet at an unnamed and unshown point.  I said none of the lines are parallel, so any two lines will meet in a point.

Comment: That makes sense.